# Cucumber feature , Java, Eclipse

Tags: cucumber-java

I am new to automation , I am trying to run Cucumber feature and gives me the following error

[image]

Comment: For future reference, please avoid adding screenshots of code to your post. It's preferred if you copy and paste error messages & code using the formatter to help the community with your problem.

Comment: Your screenshot has cut off all the information needed to give you an answer. Please don't use screenshots and see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask